# Cambio de contacto administrativo en Strato con dominio .es

Tags: servidor, dominio

Llevo bastante tiempo intentando cambiar de agente registrador de Strato a Ionos. Pues bien, os comento mi problemática.

- El dominio es un .es así que lo gestiona nic.es.
- El contacto administrativo está con un mail que no existe ni se puede crear
- El DNI del contacto administrativo también es incorrecto
- El CIF de la asociación también está como "123456" así que está mal

La única forma que me ofrece nic.es es que Strato cambie el contacto administrativo pero llevo muchas llamadas y mails y me dicen que desde Strato NO PUEDEN HACER NADA.

¿Que puedo hacer para cambiar ese contacto o como puedo forzar a Strato a que lo haga?

Me siento estafado con esta empresa, no se si este es el sitio correcto pero se me acaban las opciones.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te comento que sería bueno leyeras [ask], lamento comentarte que no somos parte del soporte técnico de la empresa en cuestión y tampoco somos abogados por lo que nuestras eventuales respuestas en este caso carecen de formalidad y validez

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no trata sobre programación

Comment: Bueno por lo que se le está pasando a mucha gente. No es programación pero los programadores nos topamos con estos problemas si no tenemos departamento de sistemas al lado.
Al final me lo han cambiado y voy a publicar la respuesta. Si me dicen  que hay que quitar la pregunta la quito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, después de probar varios tipos de correo a info@dominios.es, en uno que les mandé la fotocopia del dni y les solicité cambiar el correo electrónico me lo hicieron  y ya pude acceder.

Espero que le sirva a alguien más ya que con cada operador que he hablado me ha dicho que a la gente le pasa mucho eso con Strato